# Weird artifacts and tearing on Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: display, amd-graphics

[image: here]

That's the problem, and I don't know how to solve it. It's a fresh installation, I was using Zorin OS before with no problems. This tearing only happens after login, and for some reason the top bar does not have it. The computer have a AMD A10-9600P With 8 GBs of ram.

Comment: If you call up a terminal does it display clearly?

Comment: What video card? What version driver?

Comment: hi, i discovered thet the problem was the resolution was too high. i solved it on putting the resolution lower